# LabVIEW array index

Tags: search, labview

I am new to LabVIEW programming, and the problem is, that I need index numbers of each element in a array, and also select values by those indexes into another array, like so:

Array `13 15 16 17 18 19 12 17 17 162 626 36 828 463 565 665 565 32 587`

Index `5 6 7 8 9 12 13 14 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 21`

In the result program should get these index values .

Thanks in advance!

[image: Current code sample]

Comment: In your example, are you saying you have two input arrays `13 15 16 17 18 19 12 17 17 162 626 36 828 463 565 665 565 32 587` and `5 6 7 8 9 12 13 14` and the desired output is `20  22  23 24 25  26  27 28   29  30 21`? Can you try and explain more clearly how those inputs should produce that output please? I also don't understand how the example relates to the code you have posted.

Comment: Instead of "Equals" followed by "Or Array Elements", use "Search 1D Array"... you'll avoid the memory overhead of constructing that interim Boolean array, but more importantly, it'll be clearer what your code is attempting to do. Also, I'd rename that "String" input as "Strings" because it is an array, not a single string.

Comment: Your "In Range & Coerce" is a bug... that does STRING comparison, not numeric comparison, which means that both "15.1" and "151" will both be in the range. You need to convert your strings to numerics if you want to do numeric comparisons (use "Decimal String To Number").

Comment: Hi, nekomatic, thanks for your reply. I will try to explain you more clearly. i have a xls file which maybe you can see in my code that i read and extract the value in one array. 2nd step i searched two selective column from that file. 3rd step i search those rows values from selective column which is in the range of 16 to 15 (or any range). Now i want to get those range indexes also.

Comment: Hi srm, thanks for your reply. And i will change my code accordingly your suggestion. Here i explain my situation in above comment so if possible give some example or suggestion.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQgs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upd: here is code snippet of how to get indexes of elements in the array.
Also, there is OpenG Array library (you could install it via VI Package Manager), it has built-in function of how to get all entries of element (see it on the picture).
[image: Code snippet]
Below is the code snippet for search in 2D array:
[image: Search in 2D array]
Update: search 2D array in 2D array, LV2013 snippet
[image: Search in 2D array]

Comment: hi kosist, actually i want indexes of current array element. For example these are array element {23 32 45 56 34 56 34 75 42 57 23 56}, so i need these elements indexes (pointer addresses) for further searching.

Comment: i applied that logic but it didnt work maybe i have 2d array in which two column and i need to find both column indexes as well, please let me know if i did some mistake again, thats my implementation. Thanks

Comment: Hi kosist, Thanks for your replied. actually the element to find is also in 2d array, i tried my self to implement but i think i did something wrong again, i updated above image of my current code. please let me know where i did mistake again. Thanks

Comment: Please, make VI snippet and upload it (instead of simple screenshot) - then I'll be able to drag-and-drop snippet into block diagram, and have the code ready

Comment: Hi Kosist, i uploaded VI snippet. Please let me if it didnt work. Thanks

Comment: Hi kosist, i have labview 2012-2013, and thats VI are not opened in this could you please upload new VI which is easily opened in my version. Thanks

Comment: You could try to reimplement it by yourself... But, I've updated the snippet; check it.

Comment: Hi kosist, Thanks for updating bro. But the indexes are store double. and 2nd it is possible that we can store both column indexes i mean we have 2d array selective row in which two columns, so we can store both array indexes separately.

Comment: 1). Indexes can't be double - it does not make sense. Indexes are always I32. You can't have index of 0.5 value, or something. 2). Not clear exactly what do you mean - if you need rows and columns indexes in separate arrays, just split current 2D array into 2 columns; use Index Array function.

Comment: for example we have 10 elements in columns, so the indexes is also 10 but that program store 20 indexes. Its mean its store double indexes of 10 elements.

Comment: Of course - because for each element one stores indexes of row + column. If you need one of those, just slightly modify the code.

Comment: Hi Kosist, Sir i tried but i didn't understand nested for loops usage, just give me logic i try myself. Thanks